# Loading images using require in react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I'm new to React and I'm trying to create a game involving cards where a websocket returns an array of card names, and on the front end I generate the correct card images from a local directory of images. The card names returned from the websocket match the file name of the image, e.g. "map" corresponds to the image "map.jpg". I'm attempting to map over the array & create an image tag for each card name in the array. I read that the best way is to use `require()` and so I attempted to do something like

```
//inside component
let cardImgs;
...
socket.on(RECEIVED_STARTING_HAND, (hand) => {
     cardImgs = hand.map(cardName => <img src= {require(`../../card_images/${cardName}.jpg`)}/>
})
```

...So that later on in my component I could do something like this:

```
return (
 <div>
     <h1>My hand</h1>
        {cardImgs}
 </div>
  ...
)
```

However, `cardImgs` does not render. In my `return` statement of my component I tested out rendering an image directly and it worked, e.g.

```
const map = "map"
return (
 <div>
     <h1>My hand</h1>
        {cardImgs}
 </div>
  ...
//this one renders!!!
<img src={require(`../../card_images/${map}.jpg`)} /> 
)
```

I created my react app with Create-React-App and I read some things that said I should reconfigure my `webpack.config.js` file but then I also read some things that said I should not touch it unless I needed to. I am not sure why `require()` works when I do it in my `return` statement of my component yet it's not working when given the array of image tags. Am I missing something or do you have any suggestions on better ways to dynamically load images in React? Thank you!

Comment: use import that will surely help.

Comment: I have ~40 images and I want to dynamically load images based on the cards given. Having 40 import statements just gets messy. I was hoping there would be an alternative to that.

Comment: require doesn't work in react, the only other way I can think of would be to host the image in the cloud like AWS or Azure and then you can load it dynamically.

Comment: There is: host your static assets _as static assets_ instead of trying to bundle them in. Especially if there's data that isn't going to change every half day, like images or site CSS or webfonts. And then load them by using an `<img>` component, because that's what the `img` element is for.

Comment: @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans Can you please show an example? Do you mean host them as static assets in the cloud?

Comment: whatever your hosting solution is. If that's "the cloud" (AWS, Azuer, GCP, whatever) then sure. If you have a VPS, then on your VPS, etc. Just keep your images _normal images_ and point to their (ideally relative) URL, under the "don't try to reinvent the web" slogan. Browsers are already great at fetching, loading, caching, and displaying images.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend simply processing the state item `hand` in your render. When you update the value, a render will be triggered and create your images.

```
{hand.map((cardName, index) => (
      <img key={cardName} src={`pathtoserver/card_images/${cardName}.jpg`}/>
     ))}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-ritchie-p0kre?file=/src/App.js:0-502)

Comment: Do you happen to know what the path to the server is if you use create-react-app? I'm attempting to navigate starting from different folders but I can't find the correct path.

Comment: In create react app you won't have access to the server as it is just a lite server setup for development, if you mean your backend server that's up to you.

Comment: react does not have default access to a given server. static assets in a create-react-app are saved in `/public` if that helps you. this can help you if all your card images are kept within the react app and not in a server

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans good point, assuming nothing in the example above but will update it

Comment: nice, comment retracted. People think they can just use array position for the `key` attribute _so often_ that it's one of the main reasons why React applications run poorly, when they run poorly.

Answer (score 0):

if you want render a image from a local folder you can import images that you need with import syntax and after that use it in your img tag

```
import card1 from '../you/path/to/image.png';
import card2 from '../you/path/to/image.png';
import card3 from '../you/path/to/image.png';

const cards = {
    nameToCard1: card1,
    nameToCard2: card2,
    nameToCard3: card3,
}
```

in your socket method:

```
socket.on(RECEIVED_STARTING_HAND, (hand) => {
cardImgs = hand.map(cardName => cards[cardName] />
```

})

and in your render method:

```
return (
<div>
    <h1>My hand</h1>
    <ul>
        {cardImgs.map((img) => <li><img key={img} src={img} /></li>)}
    </ul>
</div>
```

)

i hope this help you, have a nice day.

Comment: remember to add `key` attributes when using `map` (and remember that they should be real, unique values for a component, not "array position")

Comment: Oh, you're right. I'll proceed to edit the post to get the right example

Comment: And then you did the exact thing I reminded you not to do. Use a unique **identifier**, i.e. something that _always identifies that element_: if I have `['a','b']` and `['b','a']`, did I change both elements, or did I just swap them? That's what `key` is used for. You have the perfect unique identifier already, it is right there, you're already assigning it to `src`, _use that as DOM diffing key_. Please read https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys and understand why you need to give this attribute a proper value, because using list positions is shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: Thank you for the information, I apologize, and I correct the problem using the src of the image as unique identifier

Comment: But why ```key={`${img}`}```? Just say `key={img}`? And you're using an arrow function, so: `<div><h1>..</h1><ul>{cardImgs.map(url => <li><img key={url} src={url} /></li>)}</ul></div>` and done?